# What does a duplicate-triplicate-etc ratio mean?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So, if I have three numbers such that : $\dfrac ab = \dfrac bc$

Then we have $\dfrac ac$ which is a duplicate ratio of of $\dfrac ab$

If we have $4$ numbers such that : $\dfrac ab=\dfrac bc=\dfrac cd$
Then we have $\dfrac ad$ is triplicate ratio of $\dfrac ab$
We can continue this way with other proportions.
So, what does it mean exactly ?

Comment: What is the question? You give a definition and ask what this definition is... Also you should put some constraints on the numbers ($\mathbb Z$, perhaps?) - else they will be very boring.

Comment: Yes, what I meant what is what does it mean that a fraction is duplicate ratio of another fraction ? I understand that it's a definition, but how am I supposed to interpret its meaning ?

Comment: You can only find a meaning if you give a context. For example do you want to know about any interesting properties such a triple might have? Are you asking how to construct such a triple? There is not much to it and the question is terribly broad at the moment.

Comment: I guess having an actual example would help understand it more because for me, it isn't clear.

Comment: Here is where I found it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio#Euclid.27s_definitions It's the last paragraph.

Comment: The simplest you can possibly think of is
$$\frac12 = \frac24 = \frac48 = \frac8{16} = \ldots$$

Comment: Ah, as you can see in my answer and in the linked article on [geometric progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression), that's about all there is to such sequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find such a $n$-tuple of numbers $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ such that
$$\frac{a_1}{a_2} = \frac{a_i}{a_{i+1}} \qquad \forall\ 2\le i\le n-1$$
and also $a_i \in\mathbb N\quad\forall\ 1\le i\le n$, there is a simple algorithm:

Chose numbers $k,r\in\mathbb N$ and let

$$a_i = kr^{i-1}$$

The constant ratio will be $\frac1r$ in this case and all $a_i$ will be natural numbers.

As to what you can do with it: There is not much to it and I've never heard of the definitions you gave.

For an actual example, chose $k = 1, r = 2$ then we get the boring sequence
$$\frac12 = \frac24 = \frac48 = \frac8{16} = \ldots$$

Comment: Ok, let's stop this sequence at 1/2=2/4 Then we have 1/4 is a duplicate ratio of of 1/2 .... Is that all I have to understand from it ? Duplicate means times two right ? (English isn't my first language)

Comment: Sorry, it clearly says : "if p, q and r are in proportion then p:r is the duplicate ratio of p:q" where : "It defines three terms p, q and r to be in proportion when p:q::q:r."

Comment: Sorry, I misread. In this case "duplicate" would be expressed as "square" in modern terms. $1/4$ is the square of $1/2$.

Comment: WOW !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! This is exactly what I wanted to read. It's clear now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you know that $\frac{a}{c} = \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2$ and that $\frac{a}{d} = \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^3$. Aside from that, I can't tell you much more as your question is rather vague.